# Android + Firebase Push Notification con telefono bloqueado

Tags: android, android-layout, firebase-messaging

Tengo mi aplicacion android que recibe alertas mediante FCM Push Notification mediante el metodo (Java):

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
```

Mi conflicto es que no estoy logrando que la pantalla (Activity) que se abre cuando llega la alarma, se pueda muestre no solo con la aplicacion abierta, **sino tambien con el celular bloqueado**; que saltee el patron de ingreso al celular y te permita trabajar con esa alerta de manera rapida.

Hasta ahora probe las variantes de subirle la prioridad al maximo con el NotificationBuilder, pero no hay caso...

```
NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
```

no puedo lograr que saltee el bloqueo del celular.

Desde ya muchas gracias por cualquier comentarios

Answer (score 0):

Te comento que el metodo:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
```

Esta hecho para interceptar las push notifications cuando tu aplicación esta abierta, como dice en la documentacion de Firebase:

> **Mensajes de notificación enviados cuando la app está en segundo plano**. En este caso, la notificación se entrega a la bandeja del sistema del dispositivo. Cuando un usuario presiona una notificación, abre el selector de aplicaciones de forma predeterminada.
>
> **Mensajes con cargas útiles de notificación y de datos, tanto en primer plano como en segundo**. En este caso, la notificación se entrega a la bandeja del sistema del dispositivo y la carga de datos se entrega en los adicionales del intent de tu actividad iniciadora.

En resumen cuando tu aplicacion esta en primer plano puedes interceptar la push (o no) con onMessageReceived, sino lo obtiene la bandeja del Android.

**Solucion**
Lo que debes hacer es enviar la metadata necesaria desde el servidor, por ejemplo:

```
  var message = {
  data: {
    score: '850',
    time: '2:45'
  },
  topic: topic
};
```

Esa informacion llegara a tu dispositivo a traves de un Intent en la primera pantalla que tengas, puedes capturarlo de la siguiente forma (el codigo de abajo deberia de imprimir los valores que enviaste desde Firebase):

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
    for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
        String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key);
        Log.d(TAG, "Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
    }
}
```

Espero que te haya ayudado, saludos.